# Hermeneutic Stance of Classic Phenomenology

Tags: phenomenology, hermeneutics, ricoeur

Paul Ricoeur stated that Marx, Freud, and Nietzsche were exemplars of the “hermeneutics of suspicion.” Given classic phenomenology’s attempt to faithfully describe the matters or things themselves (independent of scientific or metaphysical reality), it’s obvious Husserl and Scheler do not fall under the above umbrella.

**Question**: Does this make classic phenomenology a “hermeneutics of faith” with regard to experience? If not, is there a clear classification that can be assigned to classic phenomenology in light of Ricoeur’s comment?

Comment: Probably not, especially for the relatively more pure Husserlean epoche which doesn't presume any substantial faith for its hermeneutics if any at all, and generally Husserl's classic phenomenology avoids hermeneutics as much as possible via bracketing...

Comment: @DoubleKnot Sure. My question is about an unstated hermeneutic stance, but . . . there was an exchange between me and JD (on his now deleted first answer), where it seems I may be using Ricoeur's and Gadamer's terminology far too flippantly. My question is quickly becoming a lesson in me needing to be more careful in using jargon from those I haven't studied in depth (Ricoeur and Gadamer in this case)!

Comment: I would rather say “hermeneutics of trust” (using “hermeneutics” loosely), as in "trust but verify". There is quite a lot of intellectual discipline that goes into Husserl's *epoche*, maintaining the phenomenological attitude, "founding" intentional acts on "originary" evidence and "constituting" intentional objects, to suspect unmediated faith. Husserl was not untouched by Kant and Hegel even against himself. But yes, suspicion was not his default. In that, he also stands with them and not Marx, Freud, Nietzsche and their postmodernist progeny.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's important to unpack "hermeneutics of faith" and "hermeneutics of suspicion". Fortunately for us, there's [an article on the topic in WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeneutics_of_suspicion):

> Ruthellen Josselson similarly writes, "Ricoeur distinguishes between two forms of hermeneutics: a hermeneutics of faith which aims to restore meaning to a text and a hermeneutics of suspicion which attempts to decode meanings that are disguised... [Marx, Freud, and Nietzsche] share a commitment to unmasking 'the lies and illusions of consciousness'; they are the architects of a distinctively modern style of interpretation that circumvents obvious or self-evident meanings in order to draw out less visible and less flattering truths… Ricoeur's term has sustained an energetic after-life within religious studies, as well as in philosophy, intellectual history, and related fields.

Therefore, given that we are dealing with interpretations of text, we have to take into account that the criterion appears to be when differentiating author's works whether or not there's a notion of [false consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_consciousness) built into the text. That is, some authors are convinced in their own worldview that there is a fundamental disconnect between the appearance of reality and reality itself by the audience. An analytical philosopher of this caliber might be Noam Chomsky whose coauthoring of [*Manufacturing Consent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manufacturing_Consent) seems to echo the same notions of a public misled in beliefs by another group of people. I think it's fair to say that the hermeneutics of suspicion seems to apply to authors who are central or tangential to the ideas of modern day [critical theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_theory).

**If this reading of the criterion is accurate, that it seems perfectly acceptable to classify Husserl and his student in the second category.**

Comment: Sorry to lead you down the wrong path with the first answer. Sometimes I forget to put my thinking cap on.

Comment: No problem! Quick clarification: when you say “second category” you mean . . . which one? Just to be sure I understand correctly.

Comment: "Hermeneutics of faith" would be how Husserl and Scheler approached a text. I can't find anything in either of their descriptions that could be used to argue they saw an inherent and secret agenda in texts in the same way Marx sees capitalist influence or Chomsky sees unethical propaganda. It is important to note, however, that of course the term itself was coined by Ricoeur and therefore is applied retroactively through analysis by more contemporary philosophers and was not terminology during any of the aforementioneds' lives.

Comment: Of course, I'm not read in Continental much, so if you can get feedback from Ricoeur scholar, you'd be better off. ; ) Toto cum grano salum.